# Github actions/upload-artifact@v2 breaks with windows-latest

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following GitHub actions workflow for a C# (.net 6) project that works fine with `ubuntu-latest`. But for some reason we need it to use `windows-latest`, and it breaks with the error (**the error** message followed after **YAML workflow**).

**Yaml workflow:**

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Setup Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Restore .NET dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build .NET
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test .NET
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
    - name: Publish .NET
      run: |
        dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=Release-win-x86 -c Release
        dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=Release-win-x64 -c Release
    - name: Upload Published Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: softwarename
        path: | 
          /home/runner/work/solution/project/Software/win-x86/
          /home/runner/work/solution/project/Software/win-x64/
```

**The error:**

```
Upload Published Artifact
  Run actions/upload-artifact@v2
  Warning: No files were found with the provided path: 
  /home/runner/work/solution/project/Software/win-x86/
  /home/runner/work/solution/project/Software/win-x64/. No artifacts will be uploaded.
Download Published Artifact
  Run actions/download-artifact@v2
  Starting download for softwarename
  Error: Unable to find any artifacts for the associated workflow
```

I read [here](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/281) that I need to change actions/upload-artifact@v2 to  actions/upload-artifact@v2.2.4, and I tried and failed with the same error.

Any Idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not open a bug ticket in their repository?

Comment: @NicoHaase I might end doing that, I was just wondering if there was a work around. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give credit to @jessehouwing for making me aware of the concept.

Regarding this [thread](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1794), my solution needed `${{ github.workspace }}`, so that my changes looks like this:

```
${{ github.workspace }}\Software\win-x86
${{ github.workspace }}\Software\win-x64
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on:

```
/home/runner/work/solution/project
```

Instead use

```
${{ github.workspace }}/project
```

That way it points to the correct path for the runner independent of the operating system and configuration

Comment: same same :( "Warning: No files were found with the provided path:"

Comment: Check the output form the publish task, it should log where it copied the files to. Or issue a `cmd /c dir /s /b` to get a peek into all the files in your workspace.

Comment: Basically what you seem to be encountering are differences between Linux and Windows folders/directories'/defaults etc.

Comment:  solved! On to the next oddity ;).